# Booleans, if-else statements, and scanner?

Tags: java, object, if-statement, boolean, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make the "yes" (or "y" in this case) response to a question a true statement. Any other response to the question below is known to be a false statement.

```
System.out.print("Do you smoke?(y/n): ");
        boolean smoker = console.nextBoolean();
        if (smoker.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            smoker = true;
        } else {
            smoker = false;
        }
```

I get the error

```
HealthPlan.java:32: error: boolean cannot be dereferenced
        if (smoker.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
              ^
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I have searched this online and I am not so sure.

Comment: `smoker` is a primitive. It doesn't have methods. Also, think about it: does it make sense to try and compare a boolean against `"y"`?

Answer (score 7):

Can't cast a `String` to a `boolean`, catch the `console.next` line as a `String`. Check if it's y and then place the the value in a boolean

```
String smoker = console.nextLine();
boolean isSmoker = false;
if (smoker.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    isSmoker = true;
}
```

Comment: I would use `if (smoker.matches("(?i)y(es)?")) {` to match `y` or `yes`..

Comment: Or: `boolean isSmoker = console.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y");`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here.

First your variable `smoker` is of type `boolean`. Which is a primitive type. A primitive type is not an object, you can't call a method or an attribute on it. So you can't write `smoker.someAttribute` or `smoking.someMethod()`. This is why you get this Exception.

Second, your variable is of type `boolean` so you can only affect boolean to it. But you are trying to affect a String to it, it will obviously fail. This error is hidden cause of the first one.

---

The solution is the same for both problem. Either check directly the console input, or pass it to a `String` variable then check this variable value. Then after the check, affect the correct boolean value to `smoker`.

With the direct check :

```
boolean smoker = false;
if(console.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
    smoker = true;
}
```

With a String variable

```
boolean smoker = false;
String consoleInput = console.nextLine();
if(consoleInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
    smoker = true;
}
```